# How to fix raspberry pi 4 keyboard error?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

In raspberry pi when I try to call keyboard module i get error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "emergencyHorus.py", line 161, in <module>
    detectKeyboard()
  File "emergencyHorus.py", line 49, in detectKeyboard
    if keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_init_.py", line 417, in is_pressed
    steps = parse_hotkey(hotkey)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_init_.py", line 344, in parse_hotkey
    scan_codes = key_to_scan_codes(hotkey)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_init_.py", line 317, in     key_to_scan_codes
    t = tuple(_collections.OrderedDict((scan_code, True) for scan_code, modifier in                 _os_keyboard.map_name(normalized)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_init_.py", line 317, in <genexpr>
    t = tuple(_collections.OrderedDict((scan_code, True) for scan_code, modifier in _os_keyboard.map_name(normalized)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 153, in map_name
    if len(parts) > 1 and parts[0] in ('left', 'right'):
KeyboardInterrupt
```

In my computuer code works great. Help please.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]